# How to handle mail server configuration in spring in multi tenant environment?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, multi-tenant

I am converting a normal working application to multi tenant application. Currently I have my mail server configured now I am not able to figure out a way to configure multiple mail server per tenant.

I should be able to add mail server on the fly when new tenant is added.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of 2 options

**Option 1**

You can create a table called as `TenantSettings` in which you can store key-value pairs of data. The value column being straight forward data or json or any format.

In this you can store the data in the following format or we can store the data in the key-value pair like SMTPServer, SMTPPort etc..

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id      TenantId    Setting     Value       CreatedBy       CreatedOn ......
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       123     SMTPConfig  {SMTPServer..}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       124     SMTPConfig  {SMTPServer..}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Option 2**

We can store the tenant specific settings inside the tenant specific database itself if you are having a tenant wise database so that once tenant is identified, we can load all the settings for the tenant and use wherever required.

If you can share more details on your current models, we can build a right approach.

Comment: I am planning to use the master database to hold the information but my concern is in both the solutions provided above do we have to build the java mail sender object every time I will have to send mail?